# Softlayer Java : Custom partitions lost after OS RELOAD

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I placed an order for BareMetal and used storage groups. We received the order correctly but, after an OS reload we lost all the custom partition for other storage groups.

Here is an example:
`storageGroups = [
    {
         "arraySize": 1998,
         "arrayTypeId": 2,
         "hardDrives": [
            0,
            1
         ],
         "partitionTemplateId": 1 
     },
    {
         "arraySize": 500,
         "arrayTypeId": 2,
         "hardDrives": [
            2,
            3 
         ],
         # The custom partitions only work on other storage groups
         # different from the primary one
         "partitions": [
             {
                 "isGrow": true,
                 "name": "/test1",
                 "size": 100
             }
         ]
     },
    {
         "arraySize": 2264,
         "arrayTypeId": 9,
         "hardDrives": [
             4,
         ],
         "partitions": [
             {
                 "isGrow": true,
                 "name": "/test2",
                 "size": 500
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "arraySize": 2264,
         "arrayTypeId": 9,
         "hardDrives": [
             5,
         ],
         "partitions": [
             {
                 "isGrow": true,
                 "name": "/test3",
                 "size": 500
             }
         ]
     }
]`
`After OS reload, df -k only shows:`

`Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      xxxxxxxxxx 1290396 xxxxxxxxxx   1% /
devtmpfs         xxxxxxxx       0   xxxxxxxx   0% /dev
tmpfs            xxxxxxxx       0   xxxxxxxx   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            xxxxxxxx    9316   xxxxxxxx   1% /run
tmpfs            xxxxxxxx       0   xxxxxxxx   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          xxxxxx  136776     xxxxxx  55% /boot
tmpfs             xxxxxxx       0    xxxxxxx   0% /run/user/0`

I am using reloadOperatingSystem("FORCE", config) and only setting ssh keys in the Configuration. How can I retain the custom partitions after OS reload for the above example - /test1, /test2, /test3? Have I to create Component object and add to getHardDrives() of Configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

It is not adding all the entries to /etc/fstab after reboot so, df -k is not showing the details. I will be manually adding the entries to /etc/fstab, to avoid the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

**The custom partitions should be kept if you don't change the OS in a reload process**. In case that you are doing an OS reload with a different OS, it's necessary to send again the custom partitions in config.